# What can we do about users with a 0% accept rate?

Tags: discussion

Do we *not* answer [their](https://superuser.com/users/109486/raj) questions? Is a moderator able to step in and accept a clear, solid answer?

Comment: Accept rate has been removed, so this isn't relevant anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accepting an answer is *not* mandatory for a user - so you should not be "boycotting" users who have zero accept rate(yeah, I know that can be hard) - neither should you be badgering the user to accept their answers. Of course, few users aren't aware of the concept of accepted answers, so I generally leave this comment.

> You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

---

Coming to your other question, no, Moderators cannot force accept answers on any arbitrary question, barring their own.

Comment: *Does not accept your answer* :)

Comment: @iglvzx irony ;)

Answer (score -2):

why not? it's a credit system, why not prod the askers to give credit where credit is due?

up till this minute i didn't realize there WAS such a system ....